# Best way to render images as a video clip in a mobile device

Tags: c#, image, windows-mobile

I have tried to approach this problem several ways.

I have a web application that will load a sprite (which is a large jpeg that 'holds' 100 frames.  Using the offset of div properties I am able to 'move' the image along so it looks like a movie clip.

This works well.

I need to produce the same on mobile devices. 
I have to support Windows Mobile 6.5.
I was using jQuery/ajax to move the sprite image along to stop any flickering of the image within the browser.
Windows mobile 6.5 does not support this.

So, i decided to do a native app using C# Framework 2.0.

I thought about converting the sprite to a mp4 file and playing within a web browser control. but IE on the device will not support html5.

I have been told there is a CAB file from adobe so that I can play flash videos on the IE.  But, apart from using ffmpeg to convert these images to a flv there is not much control as to adding menu like pause,stop,play etc when playing the flv file.  I have not started any of this by the way i assume that would be the case.

So.. I thought if I download the sprite to the device i could use the graphics object of a picture box and render the rectangle of interest from large sprite to picture box.

I could not download the Sprite and save it to an image though. I get 'out of memory exception'.

I used the OpenNetCF.Drawing as it is supposed to support large files.  I still get the error message. I have reduced the size of the image and it will work on about 20 frames.

I would then have to 'stack' these images containing 20 frames and load them up when necessary.

I am beginning to wonder now whether i am doing the right thing?

Is there a different way of trying to achieve what i am trying to achieve that is quicker and more efficient as I have run out of ideas.

If I am OK doing it this way then what is the best way to render images in a picturebox like a video.  Memory efficiency says load the image from the file on the device when needed and dispose of it but that would cause 'flickering'. What IS the best way to handle multitude of images on a device?

i have plenty of code I can upload but I was worried the question would look 'messy' as I have tried so many things.  I will of course edit/upload the code as required.

Thanks.

Comment: nobody uses windows mobile 6.5 anymore... even windows phone 7 is barely used. May I ask why you are creating such a horrible headache for yourself attempting to support it?

Comment: Nobody is no consumers use WM any more. But in industrial, commercial environment WM has still its place and is running on thousands of motorola, Intermec by Honeywell and other vendor's device! Accoring to the problem of playing a video sequence on WM I would go with Windows Media Player Mobile or an animated GIF.

Comment: @krilovich Hi, josef has said it all.  I have a requirment for it from a client (groan).  Can WP be embeded within an App do you know?  Inetresting idea about the GIF as well. Thanks